# Invalid redeclaration of rawValue in Release build

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, rawrepresentable

I have a mixed project and came across an interesting issue.
There's an enum, defined in obj-c

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSUInteger, ABCCategory) {
  ABCCategoryFirst,
  ABCCategorySecond
};
```

Next, there's a swift file where an extension is defined

```
extension ABCCategory: RawRepresentable {

  public typealias RawValue = String

  public init(rawValue: RawValue) {
    switch rawValue {
    case "first":
      self = .first
    case "second":
      self = .second
    default:
      self = .first
    }
  }

  public var rawValue: RawValue {
    get {
      switch self {
      case .first:
        return "first"
      case .second:
        return "second"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Everything works fine in the Debug configuration, but when I switch to Release it does not build, saying: **Invalid redeclaration of 'rawValue'**
I've tried removing typealias, replacing RawValue with String (so the protocol could implicitly guess the value), making constructor optional as in the protocol (and implicitly unwrapped optional also) - no go.

I do understand that extending an Int enum with string is a bit weird, but why it stops building in Release and working absolutely perfect in Debug?

Is there some different mechanism of treating enums/classes/extensions for Release configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The raw value syntax for enums in Swift is “just” a shorthand for conformance to the RawRepresentable protocol. It’s easy to add this manually if you want to use otherwise unsupported types as raw values.
>   [Source](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/11/rawrepresentable/)

I'm not sure why it works in debug because when you create a typed enum you are already 'conforming' to `RawRepresentable`. So when you create an `NS_ENUM` it is imported in to swift like so:

```
public enum ABCCategory : UInt {
    case first
    case second
}
```

Meaning that it already conforms to `RawRepresentable`. The fix can be achieved two ways, one in Swift and in Objective-C

---

In Swift we just remove the `RawRepresentable` and change `rawValue` to `stringValue`, and `RawValue` to `String`:

```
extension ABCCategory {

    var stringValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .first: return "first"
        case .second: return "second"
        }
    }

    init(_ value: String) {
        switch value {
        case "first":
            self = .first
        case "second":
            self = .second
        default:
            self = .first
        }
    }

}
```

---

Or you could just change the Objective-C to use `NS_TYPED_ENUM`. Some info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html). However this will change your enum to a `struct`

.h

```
typedef NSString *ABCCategory NS_TYPED_ENUM;

extern ABCCategory const ABCCategoryFirst;
extern ABCCategory const ABCCategorySecond;
```

.m

```
ABCCategory const ABCCategoryFirst = @"first";
ABCCategory const ABCCategorySecond = @"second";
```

This will be imported by swift like so:

```
public struct ABCCategory : Hashable, Equatable, RawRepresentable {

     public init(rawValue: String)
}

public static let first: ABCCategory
public static let second: ABCCategory
```